# jQuery Validate: compareTo element in iframe, in its own form

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

Working with a deep legacy system here, no ability to go outside the current page to modify stuff.

Right now the CAPTCHA is something hand-rolled. This also cannot be replaced. The Captcha brings in two things via iFrames: the image itself, and a form containing the actual value that the field the person fills can be validated against. There is a JavaScript method that brings that value into the page, but via a global value called/filled by the onLoad attribute of the iFrame:

```
<iframe name="frmeIMGVal-Value" id="frmeIMGVal-Value" src="_Inc/Forms/DynamicImg-Value.php" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" width="0" height="0" onload="Javascript: RefreshImageClickPart3();" style="display: none;"><noframes>This web form requires that inline frames be enabled.</noframes></iframe>
```

And the iFrame itself is very spartan:

```
<?php
session_start();
$strValue = (@!isset($_SESSION['ValidationImgValue'])) ? "Not Set" : $_SESSION['ValidationImgValue'];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html>
  <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="frmImgValue" id="frmImgValue">
      <input type="hidden" name="hdnImgValue" id="hdnImgValue" value="<?php echo $strValue; ?>" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

But I cannot call the `$_SESSION['ValidationImgValue']` from within my current page, because it gets created ***AFTER*** the current page gets loaded: it gets created when the first iFrame calls in the image.

My problem is that I need to be able to access this value directly from within the [jQuery Validate code](https://jqueryvalidation.org/equalTo-method). To be specific, I have

```
txtValidateImg: {
  required: true,
  equalTo: "#chkValue"
}
```

But I need to be able to reference the global variable instead of `#chkValue`. Just putting that variable in there causes the entire script to cease functioning because it's not expecting that -- it's expecting the ID of an element, which doesn't exist in the page; it exists within a different form that exists within an iFrame that is on the page.

Please understand, I cannot modify anything outside of the page. I have already tried to read the element and pull its value:

```
$(function(){
  $('#chkValue').val(
    $('#frmeIMGVal-Value').contents().find('#hdnImgValue').val()
  );
});
```

into another hidden element on the page:

```
<input type="hidden" id="chkValue" name="chkValue" value="" />
```

but this didn’t work either (once again, all validation ceased to function).

Suggestions?

---

**EDIT:** For the curious, there is a global JS file that contains the JS which is called by the second iFrame being loaded:

```
function RefreshImageClickPart3(){
  strImgValue = window.frames['frmeIMGVal-Value'].document.forms['frmImgValue'].hdnImgValue.value;
}
```

And this file is being called from the `<head>` and works perfectly in other pages -- the value of `strImgValue` is directly accessible from other places in the page. However, when I modify my other code to such:

```
$(function(){
  $('#chkValue').val( strImgValue );
});
```

Or even just

```
$('#chkValue').val( strImgValue );
```

The hidden input field still fails to be filled.

Comment: Did you try to *"read the element and pull its value"* inside an onload handler, when the iFrame has actually loaded?

Comment: If that is not what I did in the second to last code block, you just might have to pull out the crayons and construction paper. Because that code block is at the very end of the page, right before the closing `</body>`. As you can see, I access the required value and then stuff it into the hidden `#chkValue` input element.